# Style vs. Consistency when deciding between return value and 'callback'

Tags: c++, c++03

The code I'm currently re-working works something like this (pre-C++11):

**FOO.CPP**

```
if (CONDITION)
{
    SyncThing thing;
}
else
{
    AysncThing thing;
}

complete(bool isSuccess)
{
    // parses status and clears up
}
```

where SyncThing and AsyncThing are as follows:

**SYNCTHING.CPP**

```
SyncThing::SyncThing()
{
    // some complex synchronous stuff that calls Foo::complete() when done.
}
```

**ASYNCTHING.CPP**

```
AsyncThing::AsyncThing()
{
    // some complex asynchronous stuff that calls Foo::complete() when done.
}
```

In the interest of not having constructors do complicated stuff and avoiding the non-obvious code path of the constructors calling Foo::complete() when done, I want to remove the complex stuff from SyncThing's constructor and put it in a separate function that's called from Foo.cpp's logic, as follows:

**FOO.CPP**

```
if (CONDITION)
{
    SyncThing thing;
    bool didTheThing = thing.doSomeComplexSyncStuff();       
    complete(didTheThing);
}
else
{
    AysncThing thing;
}

complete(bool isSuccess)
{
    // parses status and clears up
}
```

I think that makes the code path easier to follow.

My questions as as follows:

1. Ignoring AsyncThing, *is* my bool-return version of the SyncThing better and simpler than having the constructor of SyncThing or SyncThing::doSomeComplexSyncStuff() calling Foo::Complete() when done?
2. Overall, given that the 'callback' style returning is necessary when it comes to AsyncThing, is it better to keep the consistency and do the same for SyncThing, even if the answer to 1. is positive?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You should generally not do advanced initializing in a constructor. Merely initializing its member variables. Consider an init function for complex initialization.

Comment: This seems like something that you should use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) for.

Comment: I don't think this question can be reasonably answerered here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't see him mentioning C++11 or C++14?

Comment: `AysncThing thing();` is wrong. In fact, can't you post real code? There are so many ambiguities in this pseudo-C++ you've chosen to use to explain your goal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm afraid I'm using pre-C++11.

Comment: @Neijwiert: Versions from this decade are assumed unless a requirement is otherwise stated (which it now has been)

Comment: Then maybe use the [proactor design pattern together with Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html)? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion the best Thing would be when you do something like `SyncThing.setCompletedFunction(&complete)` for `SyncThing` and `AsyncThing`. This makes it clear for both

Comment: No, because in the case of asynch you would need to make sure the reference you pass survives until the callback.

Comment: @Neijwiert: OF COURSE you Need to make sure that it survives. But you Need to make sure for that in any case!

Comment: Which would make your code pretty dirty to use in the case of callbacks. One should use as little references as possible when threading to avoid such bugs. And what about a static function?